# sort list of beans manually without comparator

Tags: java

```
public class Organization {

    protected List<Address> addresses;
    protected String SourceId;
    protected String organizationId;
    protected String organizationName;
}
public class ReferenceOrg{
public List<Organization> getAllOrgs() {
        List<Organization> listOfOrgsTemp = new ArrayList<Organization>();
        List<Organization> listOfOrgs = new ArrayList<Organization>();
        listOfOrgsTemp.addAll(webToolWS.getAllProviders());
        listOfOrgsTemp.addAll(webToolWS.getAllVendors());
        for(Organization org : listOfOrgsTemp) {
            listOfOrgs.add(org);
        }
        return listOfOrgs;
    }
}
```

I wanted to sort listOfOrgs by organizationname, but I cannot implement comparator on my organisation class , it is used by different projects and they want to sort on differnt field. with out modifiying organisation class how can i sort listofOrgs list manually.`enter code here`

Comment: You should google how to use a Comparator it. You can use Collections.sort() and pass the list with an custoum comparator without changing anything in the class.

Comment: @hanu--Note my Answer. Hope it helps get you started. You supply a `Comparator` and use `Collections.sort(...,...)` where first argument is list to sort and second is name of `Comparator`. The lines with `// *****` flag or surround code to add. Inside the `Comparator` is one line to focus on: `return o1.compareTo(o2)` which compares the strings o1 and o2 and returns 1 if equal, -1 if o1<o2, 1 if o1>o2.

Answer (score 0):

I just learned how to use a `Comparator` to sort a `JTable` with numeric string data with commas. I didn't try to execute my addition to your code (and had to delete some of your references to get compilation) but maybe this will help get you started. Lines flagged with or surrounded by `// *******` show code to add.

```
public class ReferenceOrg
{

  static Comparator compareOrgs; // ***********************

  public List<Organization> getAllOrgs() 
  {
    // ************************************************************
    compareOrgs = (Comparator) new Comparator() 
    {
      @Override public int compare(Object oo1, Object oo2) 
      {
        Organization or1 = (Organization)oo1;
        Organization or2 = (Organization)oo2;
        String o1 = or1.organizationId;
        String o2 = or2.organizationId;
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
      }
    };
    // ************************************************************

    List<Organization> listOfOrgsTemp = new ArrayList<Organization>();
    List<Organization> listOfOrgs = new ArrayList<Organization>();
    ...
    for(Organization org : listOfOrgsTemp) {
        listOfOrgs.add(org);
    }

    Collections.sort(listOfOrgs, compareOrgs); // *******************

    return listOfOrgs;
  }
```

From Javadoc:

```
java.util.Collections 
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c) 
Sorts the specified list according to the order induced by the specified comparator. 
All elements in the list must be mutually comparable using the specified comparator
 (that is, c.compare(e1, e2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the list). 
This sort is guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort. 
The specified list must be modifiable, but need not be resizable. 
Implementation Note: 
This implementation defers to the List.sort(Comparator) method using the specified list and comparator. 
Parameters: 
list - the list to be sorted.
c - the comparator to determine the order of the list. A null value indicates that the elements' 
natural ordering should be used.
```

Comment: @hanu--Glad to have helped. Please mark mine as the accepted Answer by clicking the check mark.

Comment: @hanu--your "reputation points" (17) suggest that you are new to SO, so maybe you don't know the importance of accepting Answers: it adds rep points to the total of the guy who spent the time to give the Answer, especially if it actually works! By the way, you also get rep points for accepting an Answer, so it works for both of us.

Comment: @hanuu--are you there?